# Best way to rebuild this figure with html/css

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have these (simple) question. I want to rebuild the following figure with html/css

http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/3429/iunjflkr_png.htm

My suggestion 1 (just pseudo-code without any css formatting): 

table within a div

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
     <td>blue</td>
     <td>headline</td>
     <td>
       <input type="radio" ..><input type="radio" ..>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

My suggestion 2 (just pseudo-code without any css formatting): 

divs within a div

```
<div>
  <div>blue</div>
  <div>headline</div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" ..><input type="radio" ..>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is one of my suggestions usable or is there any other (better) suitable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using only div and some css. Avoid using table here as Oriol said.
Here is a sample code:

HTML code:

```
<div>
  <div class='MainBar'>
   <div class='arrow'></div>
   <div class='text'>
     <p>text goes here</p>
   </div>
   <div class='ja'>
     <p>Ja</p>
   </div>
   <div class='nein'>
     <p>Nein</p>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS code:

```
.MainBar{
width: 990px;
max-width: 990px;
height: 80px;
border: 1px solid GREY;
}

.arrow{
width: 110px;
height: 80px;
background-color: #5B9BD5;
float: left;
}

.text{
width: 660px;
height: 80px;
float: left;
}

.ja{
width: 110px;
height: 80px;
background-color: #5B9BD5;
float: left;
}

.nein{
width: 110px;
height: 80px;
background-color: #D8D8D8;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
I was not sure whether using so many divs is good style of coding or not. 
If there is no other solution i try it with the divs solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<table>` only for tabular data. If not, it's semantically incorrect.

Your case doesn't seem tabular data to me, so I suggest you to use `div`s or `span`s.

Or, if you consider it a list, you could also use

```
<li>
    Wird das Merkmal zweiseitig toleriert?
    <ul>
        <li>ja</li>
        <li>nein</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  
  
Maybe i could use a list within a div like:  
  
`<div><ul><li>...</li><li>...</li><li>...</li></ul></div>`  
  
the li-elements should be arranged horicontally, what do you mean?

Comment: @user2948467 Yes, it's an other possibility, but I'm not sure if a single question could be considered a list (a list with only one item is a bit weird)

Comment: The final result should be something like this:  
      `<ul>
        <li>Figure 1 like above</li>
        <li>Figure 2 like above</li>
        <li>Figure n like above</li>
      </ul>' 

My question relates to a correct building of one figure. Therefore the idea using a list within a list contains at least 3 elements. First => blue square with an arrow inside; Second => headline ; Third => Group of radio buttons.  

I hope it got more clear.